# Why would image become blur after applying rotation 3D effect in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I was learning the animation in SwiftUI through hackingwithswift.com and as part of this I created a small app where if user picks correct answer (the country flag) the image will rotate 360 degree on Y-Axis.

After I applied the rotation the image tend to become blur. See below images

**Launch screen**
[image]

**After I click the correct flag**
(Compare the flag in below and above image)
[image]

**After the new game re-loaded**
(The placeholder is now showing next image blur as well)
[image]

Below is the relevant SwiftUI Code.

Any suggestion why would image become blur after rotation?

I removed animation and no blurring happens. Also the blurring is consistent whichever correct button I click. In above images I just showed first instance. I temporarily disabled the Alert box as well just to see if the display of Alert is somehow causing this weird behaviour but still blurring.

```
    struct FlagImage : View{
    var image: Image
    
    var body: some View{
        image
            .renderingMode(.original)
    }
}


var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
        VStack{
            Text("Pick the flag for")
            
            Text(countryFlags[correctAnswer])
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.black)
            
            VStack{
                ForEach(0..<3) { number in
                    Button(action: {
                        if number == self.correctAnswer {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.rotationAngle += 360
                            }
                        }
                        self.flagClicked(number)
    
                    }) {
                        FlagImage(image: Image(self.countryFlags[number]))
                            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees((number == self.correctAnswer) ? self.rotationAngle : 0.0), axis: (x:0, y:1, z:0))
                    }
                }
                
                Text("Your score is \(self.userScore)")
            }.alert(isPresented: $showingResult) {
                Alert.init(title: Text("Result"), message: Text(self.resultMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("Continue"), action: {
                    self.correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
                    self.countryFlags.shuffle()
                    self.rotationAngle = 0.0
                }))
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

private func flagClicked(_ number: Int){
    if number == self.correctAnswer{
        self.userScore += 1
        self.resultMessage = "You picked correct flag.\nYour score is \(self.userScore)"
    }
    else{
        self.userScore -= 1
        self.resultMessage = "Wrong! Thats the flag for \(self.countryFlags[number]).\nYour score is \(self.userScore)"
    }
    self.showingResult.toggle()
}
```

Comment: As far as I could make this code working the issue is not reproducible with Xcode 12b3

Comment: hmm. Thats strange. Mine is Version 11.5 (11E608c). I just noticed that after playing the game randomly say for longer rounds like 10 to 15 rounds, the blur-ness do get corrected  in between and also get blurred again. So to me it looks like some interplay of state changes like resetting correctAnswer and which button is now correct causing blur-ness to randomly disappear and come again. Not sure where is the bug.

Comment: Got it. Unsure about the image blurring but my aim was to rotate button but inadvertently I attached the rotation to Image. After I attached rotation code to button I got what I was supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

The aim was to rotate button of the flag not the image of the flag. After I attached rotation code to Button I got what I was looking to do.

```
VStack{
                    ForEach(0..<3) { number in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.flagClicked(number)
                        }) {
                            FlagImage(image: Image(self.countryFlags[number]))
                        }.rotation3DEffect(.degrees((number == self.correctAnswer) ? self.rotationAngle : 0.0), axis: (x:0, y:1, z:0))
              
                    }
```